# Is there any way to sort an Array elements into variables?

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote a function that reads the attributes from the database and returns the value in the array:

```
public function test($username) {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE username = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        }
```

I want to separate the array elements into variables.

```php
require_once __DIR__.'/DbOperations.php';
$db = new DbOperations(); 
$file_path =$db->test($_POST['username']);
//var_dump($file_path); 
foreach($file_path as $value){
    //echo $value . "<br>";
    $i=0;
    $i=$i+1;
    if ($i=1)
    $username=$value;
    if ($i=2)
    $role=$value;
    if ($i=3)
    $URL=$value;
}
echo $username. $role.$URL."<br>";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You might want to check what is the right syntax to use the "is equal to" comparison inside an if statement in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic variable names:

```
foreach ($file_path as $key=>$value) {
  $$key = $value;
}
```

I'm struggling to see why that's better than having them all grouped together in a nice array, but that might be outside the scope of the question.

Your code will struggle because you set `$i=0` in every iteration, and then in every `if` statement you assign it another value. Have a read up about the difference between `=`, `==` and `===` for assignment vs. comparison operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing the function `extract`. It turns array keys into variables.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php